# I want to intercept api calls before they are passed on to redux saga to check whether Access Token needs to be refreshed

Tags: reactjs, middleware, refresh-token

I am using redux saga in my project to send api calls, now I want to check the access token expiry time before each call.
The flow will be before each call is sent, check whether the access token is about to be expired.
If it is going to expire, I will send the refresh token call with my access and refresh token and once I get back my new access token I will send my original call along with this new access token.
After research I realised that I needed a middleware(apart from saga middleware), to intercept these calls and check whether access token has expired, if so then dispatch refresh token call and after it's successful response send the call that was waiting.
Therefore, I followed the following tutorial to create another middleware,
https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/overview-redux-middleware-react-applications

but this new middleware doesn't get triggered.
This is my appStore,

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const JWTMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const middleware = [];
// middleware.push(JWTMiddleware);
middleware.push(sagaMiddleware);
const componseEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const AppStore = createStore(
  AppReducers,
  componseEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware, JWTMiddleware))
);

// JWT Middleware
JWTMiddleware.run(jwtSaga);

// // saga middleware
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default AppStore;
```

my saga middleware

```
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([...UsersSagas, ...CustomerSagas, ...CommentSagas, ...OpportunitySagas]);
}
```

and my new middleware, which I'm just trying to initialise right now,

```
// export default function* jwtSaga() { // I removed this line because I want the next action, like //below

const jwtSaga = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  console.log("dispatching", action);
  console.log("previous state", store.getState());
  next(action);
  console.log("new state", store.getState());
};
// }
```

Can anyone please guide me whether middleware is the right option for the flow that I described and if so what am I doing wrong while creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I only had to remove this line,

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
```

and instead of adding JWTMIddleware in applyMiddleware, I uncommented the following line,

```
middleware.push(JWTMiddleware);
```

my middleware works now.